# Liferay hook: filter url giving filterstart error and current url generates exception null

Tags: hook, liferay, servlet-filters, autologin

I'm trying to make an autologinfilter in Eclipse using a liferay hook.

Now I've added the:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myautologinfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>bla.bla.xyz</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myautologinfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/c/login/myurl</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

to the liferay hook's web.xml.

In the liferay-hook.xml I added: `<portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>`

And in that hook.xml I added: `auto.login.hooks=bla.bla.xyz`

bla.bla.xyz implements AutoLogin, but for now it's pretty gutted:

```
@Override
    public String[] login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AutoLoginException {
        Object parameters = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.query_string");
        Map<String, String> x = parserClass.parsing(parameters.toString());

        System.out.println("voornaam: " + geparsdeParameters.get("tokenvalue1"));


        try {
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AutoLoginException(e);
        }

    }
```

Since the hook doesn't start when I add the filtering I removed it and just tried:

http://localhost:8080/c/portal/login?tokenvalue1=55

but when I check my tomcat I see: `Error XYZ Url: url myUsedUrl exception null`

Also I tried adding some util classes but I got `classnotfoundexception`s.

Is there anything specific I have to do when I add extra classes in a hook?

Answer (score 0):

You should not add your filter in web.xml - just add it to *auto.login.hooks* property. Original property from LR 6.0.5 portal.properties:

```
auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.CASAutoLogin,\
    com.liferay.portal.security.auth.FacebookAutoLogin,\
    com.liferay.portal.security.auth.NtlmAutoLogin,\
    com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenIdAutoLogin,\
    com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenSSOAutoLogin,\
    com.liferay.portal.security.auth.RememberMeAutoLogin,\
    com.liferay.portal.security.auth.SiteMinderAutoLogin
```

Override this property in *portal-ext.properties* file - add *bla.bla.xyz* to the end of chain or replace all filters with yours.

Comment: but then it is linked to c\portal\login. The point was to map it to another url.